# Adicionar sites em script PopUp

Tags: javascript, script, popup

Possuo esse script para abrir 1 determinado site a cada dia.

Seria possivel adionar outros sites?

Exemplo: Popup abriu para usuario e se acessar ele novamente ira abrir 1 segundo site, e se acessar outra vez ira abrir um terceiro e assim por diante.

Gostaria de adicionar pelo menos uns 10 ou 20 sites.

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].onclick = function () {
        if (LerCookie('hellpop') != "1") {
            abreJanela()
        }
        GerarCookie('hellpop', '1', 1)
    }
}
function abreJanela() {
    var l = screen.availWidth;
    var t = screen.availHeight;
    var p = 'height=' + t + ',width=' + l + ',menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,left=0,top=0';
    nw = window.open("https:siteexemplo.com.br", "nt", p);
    this.focus()
}
function GerarCookie(strCookie, strValor, lngDias) {
    var dtmData = new Date();
    if (lngDias) {
        dtmData.setTime(dtmData.getTime() + (lngDias * 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var strExpires = "; expires=" + dtmData.toGMTString()
    } else {
        var strExpires = ""
    }
    document.cookie = strCookie + "=" + strValor + strExpires + "; path=/"
}
function LerCookie(strCookie) {
    var strNomeIgual = strCookie + "=";
    var arrCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrCookies.length; i++) {
        var strValorCookie = arrCookies[i];
        while (strValorCookie.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            strValorCookie = strValorCookie.substring(1, strValorCookie.length)
        }
        if (strValorCookie.indexOf(strNomeIgual) == 0) {
            return strValorCookie.substring(strNomeIgual.length, strValorCookie.length)
        }
    }
    return null
}
function ExcluirCookie(strCookie) {
    GerarCookie(strCookie, '', -1)
}
```

Comment: Basta abrir os _sites_ em ordem, ou tem que escolher aleatoriamente?

Comment: Poder ser aleatoriamente, basta que sempre abra 1 diferente ao acessar o script.

Comment: Lamento não poder lhe ajudar eu não sei nada sobre wordpress. Aproveita e marca minha resposta como aceita se ela resolveu seu problema.

Comment: só alterar $(".myHref") para $("a") editei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

> **Abrir uma pop diária clicando em qualquer link do seu documento.**

Biblioteca jquery-1.8.3.min.js e script.

o mobile detect é da resposta do Lollipop em [mobile detect](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87446/como-n%C3%A3o-executar-script-em-aparelhos-mobiles-no-wordpress/87455#87455)

O valor do cookie **yourCookie** (2 ocorrências) na function checkCookie() pode ser alterado.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
 }

 function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
   var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
     var c = ca[i];
     while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
     }
     if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
     }
   }
   return "";
 }

 var show;

 function checkCookie() {
   var user=getCookie("yourCookie");
   if (user == "") {
     show="yes";
     setCookie("yourCookie", "1", 1);
   }
 }

 var isMobile = false;
 if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
|| /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;


 if(isMobile == false){

   $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".myHref").on('click', function() {

        if (show=="yes") {
                Url = new Array;
                Url[0] = "URL_SITE";
                Url[1] = "URL_SITE";
                Url[2] = "URL_SITE";
                //acrescente quantas linhas forem necessários seguindo a ordem numérica do indice do array Ex: Url[3] = "URL_SITE"; e não esqueça de alterar URL_SITE pelos URLS dos sites desejados


                Chooselink = Math.round(Math.random() * (Url.length));

                var l = screen.availWidth;
                var t = screen.availHeight;
                var p = 'toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width='+l+',height='+t+',left=0,top=0';
                nw = window.open(Url[Chooselink],'nt',p);
                this.focus()
        }

    });

 });

}

</script>
```

HTML

1- Faz uso de evento onload na tag body:  `<body onload="checkCookie()">`

2- Em todas as tags a do seu documento que devem acionar a abertura da popup insira o parâmetro class: `<a class="myHref" .....`

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
<a class="myHref" href="suaURL">texto do link</a>
```

Caso não queira usar classe nos links para apontar somente aqueles links que devem abrir a pop, você poderá alterar a seguinte parte do código para que todos os links abram uma pop:

```
 $(".myHref").on('click', function() {
```

**para**

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
```

Os links poderão permanecer como estão ou retirar o atributo `class="myHref"`

> Se você não estiver 100% certo de que você precisa deste pop-up, isso quer dizer que você não precisa dele. Inúmeros sites perdem visitantes a cada vez que uma janela inesperada se abre, deixando-os com raiva e levando-os a sair do site.

Comment: Testei o script e não sei se faltou alguma coisa pq ele não funciona. eu apenas peguei o script que vc deixou adicionei as urls mas ele não funcionou, esses outros codigos que vc deixou depois do script eu não adicionei.

Comment: Se vc não colocou  <body onload="checkCookie()"> Não vai funcionar nem a pau Juvenal rs :)

Comment: Essa parte <body onload="checkCookie()"> deve ser colocada após </head> ?

Comment: seu documento tem <body> se tiver troque por  <body onload="checkCookie()"> Geralmente é depois de </head>  sim

Comment: Leo se vc tiver conhecimento em wordpress da uma olhada nessa pergunta que fiz http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197094/mostrar-imagem-no-twitter-cards-do-wordpress-sem-plugin

Comment: Acho que o erro do codigo está aqui  <a class="myHref"   não tem como eu altera todos os links do site e adiciona essa parte. o primeiro script que te passei ele reconhece os links automatico. o script que vc fez só funciona se algum link estiver entre <a class="myHref".  o ideal seria que qualquer link que estiver entre <a href="http://.html" "></a> o script funcione, e não é o caso

Comment: Não tem como altera o script para que ele reconheça os links que estiverem entre <a href="http://.html" "></a> o script funcione ?

Comment: só alterar  $(".myHref") para $("a") editei a resposta