# Mostrar imagem no Twitter Cards do WordPress sem plugin

Tags: wordpress, funções, script

Possuo esse Codigo, para adicionar Twitter Cards sem a necessidade de 1 plugin, apenas adicionando o codigo no functions.php.

O codigo funciona, mas a imagem do artigo só aparece se tiver anexado ao post.

Gostaria de altera ele para que mostre a 1 imagem do artigo independente se ela estiver anexada.

```
function my_twitter_cards() {
if (is_singular()) {
    global $post;
$twitter_user = str_replace('@', '', get_the_author_meta('twitter'));
$twitter_url = get_permalink();
$twitter_title = get_the_title();
$twitter_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$twittercard_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
$twittercard_thumb = $twittercard_image[0];
if (!$twittercard_thumb) {
    $twittercard_thumb = 'http://www.example.com/default-image.png';
}
if ($twitter_user) {
    echo '<meta name="twitter:creator" value="@' . esc_attr($twitter_user) . '" />' . "\n";
}
echo '<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary" />' . "\n";
echo '<meta name="twitter:url" value="' . esc_url($twitter_url) . '" />' . "\n";
echo '<meta name="twitter:title" value="' . esc_attr($twitter_title) . '" />' . "\n";
echo '<meta name="twitter:description" value="' . esc_attr($twitter_excerpt) . '" />' . "\n";
echo '<meta name="twitter:image" value="' . esc_url($twittercard_thumb) . '" />' . "\n";
echo '<meta name="twitter:site" value="@mhthemes" />' . "\n";
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_twitter_cards');
```

Comment: Como o código deve saber qual imagem usar se ela não estiver anexada ao post?

Answer (score 1):

Deve criar uma função auxiliar para puxar a imagem destacada ou na sua falta qualquer imagem associada ao post específico. Tudo falhando, colocar uma imagem default do site.

Aqui, confere se o post tem a imagem destacada e se tiver faz o `wp_get_attachment_...`:

```
$featured = has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
```

Se não tiver, puxa todas as imagems do post, ou somente 1:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1, // todas as imagens, trocar pra 1 se quiser só uma
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
// puxar as informações do attachment usando o post->ID dela
```

PS: é o tipo de código muito fácil e simples de usar como plugin. Assim, o Twitter Card vai funcionar quando trocar o Theme sem precisar ficar copiando/colando do `functions.php`. Também pode usar o plugin em outros sites facilmente.